# How did Grindelwald know about Second World War and nuclear bombings?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

**Grindelwald delivers a speech in *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*.**

[image: Gellert Grindelwald spreads his message in Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald]

[[Image src: pottermore]](https://www.pottermore.com/image/grindelwald-speech)

> The Crimes of Grindelwald take place in **1927**.

- But Gellert Grindelwald revealed a vision of the future Second World
  War in his speech in *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*.
- The vision was included with nuclear holocaust.

**How did Grindelwald know about the Second World War and nuclear bombings?**

Comment: Without having seen the movie, don't you answer your own question by stating "But Gellert Grindelwald **revealed a vision of the future** Second World War ..." Or are you just saying he's talking about it, but there's no real reference as to how he came about the knowledge in the movie? If there truly is a vision, then there's your answer.

Comment: Did they show Grindelwald's vision? If he had a vision, then he'd have known. Isn't it self explanatory?

Comment: Have you seen the movie ?

Comment: As explained in my first comment, no I have not. I'm just pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Quite simply because, he is a seer.

> **A [seer](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seer) is a gifted wizard or witch who has the ability to see
> into the future with their Inner Eye. Seers predict prophecies, which
> are then recorded and stored in the Hall of Prophecy in the Ministry
> of Magic's Department of Mysteries.** According to Minerva McGonagall,
> true Seers are extremely rare, and she had doubt that Sybill Trelawney
> can be considered as one despite her sporadically accurate
> predictions. Albus Dumbledore once told Harry Potter **that seeing into
> the future is incredibly difficult because of the complexity of every
> single action and their consequences.**

**AND Confirmed by J. K. Rowling in a Dec 2016 [tweet](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/810753569808875520) and on [Grindelwald's](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gellert_Grindelwald) Wiki Page:**

> Divination: **Grindelwald was a Seer**. **He had a vision about the
> existence of a powerful Obscurial linked to Credence Barebone.
> However, Grindelwald is seemingly not an expert in this magical field,
> as he initially misinterpreted his vision**, believing that Credence
> would lead him to the Obscurial child while in fact, Credence was the
> Obscurial himself. It should be noted, however, that Credence is the
> only known Obscurial ever to have survived past the age of ten, so
> Grindelwald could possibly not have anticipated this. Indeed, while
> possibly not an expert in Divination, **Grindelwald's raw Seer power was
> phenomenal, to the point that twelve years prior to the Muggles
> starting the Second World War, Grindelwald predicted it in detail, and
> was able to use his skull-hookah to project fearsome images of the
> future Blitzkrieg, Holocaust**, and atomic bombings for attendees of his
> rally to see. At the end of his life, Grindelwald claimed that he knew
> that Lord Voldemort would come to him in Nurmengard, which might be
> another instance of Grindelwald's Seer foresight.

---

The concept of Seers and Divianation were introduced in the Harry Potter films & novels. Professor Trelawney (played by Emma Thompson) does seem to have the gift, despite that Hermione Granger or Professor McGonagall may lack some understanding of how it may work for some, as Trelawney seemed to act more as medium of information, as opposed to seeing visions the way Grindelwald appears to.

[image: PoA - Hermione & Sybil]

Comment: I'm not surprised he's seeing things, considering how much he's toking up. Opium is quite a drug.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Seeing things is easy. Seeing things that are actually there is markedly more difficult.